# Problems using findViewById in class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a class to reuse for reviews/quizzes that have multiple choice options in the form of radio buttons.

Using the following function I have no problems on a single activity

```
public void onClickListenerButton(){
    radioGroupReview = (RadioGroup)  findViewById(R.id.radioGroupReview);
    btnReviewSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReviewSubmit);

    btnReviewSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int selection = radioGroupReview.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radio_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(selection);

            if(selection==R.id.radioCorrectAnswer) {
                textrReviewResult.setText("Correct!");
                btnReviewContinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnReviewSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                textReviewResult.setText("Try Again.");

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Applying this to a class has proven difficult as I am unsure how to replace the findViewById(selection) therefore throwing off the If/Else logic below.

```
public class ReviewLogic {

    public void onClickListenerButton(final Button btnSubmit, final Button btnContinue, final RadioGroup radioGroup,final RadioButton radioButton, final TextView result){

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int selection = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selection);

                if(selection==R.id.radioCorrectAnswer) {
                    result.setText("Correct!");
                    btnContinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    result.setText("Try Again.");
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

What substitutions can I consider to make the logic still work but exclude findViewById?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I understood, you can not just write `findViewById` because you in the not in the Activity, so  you want to find alternative to it, right?

Comment: Correct. I would like to use this as a reusable class in multiple activities rather than editing per activity.

Comment: Assuming that the `RadioButton`s are childs of your `RadioGroup`, you can use `radioGroup.findViewById(selection);`. Where are you using the `radioButton` though, it seems unused...

Comment: Why are you using a class at all?

Comment: @cricket_007 Because I need about 50 of these. Trying to limit reproduction of code

Comment: From what I can tell, you need one method in one class. Use 50 `Question` objects, not 50 Activities or XML layouts

Comment: @cricket_007 yes saying 50 objects would be a better term. However the objects will appear in different activities as a review of information in that activity.

Comment: As long as the radio button options and the logic of the submit button are the same, one only need one layout (therefore one Activity), and you simply "swap" the contents of the question when there's a correct answer. Anyways, it's not clear why you need `findViewById` in the other class. 1) you don't use that radio button variable later in the method 2) you already passed it in as a parameter

Comment: The radioButton is present to display which button of the radioGroup is selected to check for a correct answer. I may need to look into other ways of using radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `radioGroup` before `findViewById` so you will have something like:

```
radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(selection);
```

Comment: or you can add the activity that access that class as constructor parameter. Like `ReviewLogic rl = new ReviewLogic(activity)`

Comment: How then do I resolve the if(selection==R.id.radioWrongAnswer) below?

Comment: @BR89 it depends. If your RadioGroups through all activities will have children with same id, then leave it as it is. If each RadioGroup in each activity provides their own pack of ids for RadioButton, then you need to pass id of "correct" radio button, as a parameter

Comment: My problem them is converting the `int selection` to be accepted as a boolean when compared to radioCorrectAnswer.  if(selection==radioCorrectAnswer) cannot be compared as is.

Comment: Sorry, could you please expand more your problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass activity object to onClickListenerButton funtion

the access radioButton by

```
radioButton = (RadioButton)activity.findViewById(selection);
```